# How to make post and comment count unclickable with dashboard_glance_items hook

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, dashboard

I have a multi author site and I have already used some hooks to stop them from viewing other author's posts and media. Now, in the Wordpress Dashboard in the "at a glance" section it shows them the total posts and comments. They can click on them at the moment and I would like them to not be able to do this.

So, I have found a hook which targets this, although I'm only starting to learn how to customise using hooks so I need some help. Here is what I have right now, just echoing out the current user's ID to verify that it is the right hook:

```
add_filter('dashboard_glance_items', 'make_unclickable');

function make_unclickable( $items = array() ) {
    global $current_user;
    echo $current_user->ID;

    return $items;
}
```

So, how can I make the links unclickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dashboard_glance_items` filter is only useful for modifying the extra elements. The posts/comments data elements have already been displayed.

Here are three ideas:

### Method #1 - Use the `dashboard_glance_items` filter:

You can use the following filter setup, to remove the posts/pages/comments elements from the output of `wp_dashboard_right_now()`.

The trick is simple, foul WordPress to think there are no posts/comments/pages.

Here's one implementation (I'm sure I can refine this further):

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'custom_do_meta_boxes', 99, 2 );

function custom_do_meta_boxes( $screen, $place )
{
    if( 'dashboard' === $screen && 'normal' === $place )
    {   
        add_filter( 'wp_count_posts', 'custom_wp_count_posts' );
        add_filter( 'wp_count_comments', 'custom_wp_count_comments' );
    }
}

function custom_wp_count_posts( $stats )
{
    static $filter_posts = 0;
    if( 1 === $filter_posts )
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $filter_posts++;
    return null;
}

function custom_wp_count_comments( $stats )
{
    static $filter_comments = 0;
    if( 1 === $filter_comments )
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $filter_comments++;
    return array( 'total_comments' => 0 );
}
```

Then you can add the posts/pages/comments elements again via the `dashboard_glance_items` filter.

### Method #2 - Reuse the `wp_dashboard_right_now()` output:

Here's one hack, where we remove the current *Right Now* widget and add another *Custom Right Now* widget:

```
/**
 * Replace the 'Right Now' dashboard widget with our own.
 */

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup',                               
    function()
    {
        // Remove the current 'Right Now' dashboard widget:
        remove_meta_box(
           'dashboard_right_now', 
           'dashboard', 
           'normal'  
        );

        // Add our 'Custom Right Now' dashboard widget:
        add_meta_box(
           'custom_wp_dashboard_right_now',
           __( 'Custom Right Now' ),
           'custom_wp_dashboard_right_now', 
           'dashboard', 
           'normal', 
        );

    }
);
```

where our simple demo callback is:

```
function custom_wp_dashboard_right_now()
{
        // Let wp_dashboard_right_now() do all the hard work:
        ob_start();
        wp_dashboard_right_now();
        $html = ob_get_contents();                                  
        ob_end_clean();

        // Modify the output.

        // Simple example where all links are stripped out:
        echo strip_tags( $html, '<p><div><span><ul><ol><li>' );
}
```

Here we use the output buffering to catch the content from `wp_dashboard_right_now()` and then replace all the links from it.

This is just a simple example. You might need to use `preg_replace()` to target only the posts/comments items.

You could also pick up the relevant parts from the `wp_dashboard_right_now()` core function to use in the `custom_wp_dashboard_right_now()` callback.

### Method #3 - CSS/Javascript

We could also modify these links via CSS/Javascript. But I leave the implementation to you ;-)

---

I hope you can modify this to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no 'filter' to remove or edit the **previous** items in the 'At Glance' box.

**EDIT**

I removed the "Wordpress Core Hack" part because I don't want to encourage such a behavior, and I don't want you to edit the code every time Wordpress releases a new version :)

And here is a code to append custom post types stats without being clickable :

```
add_filter('dashboard_glance_items', 'make_unclickable');

function make_unclickable( $items  ) {

 $post_types = array( 'post_type_1', 'post_type_2' );

foreach( $post_types as $type ) {

    if( ! post_type_exists( $type ) ) continue;

    $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $type );

    if( $num_posts ) {

        $published = intval( $num_posts->publish );
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $type );

        $text = _n( '%s ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name, '%s ' . $post_type->labels->name, $published, 'your_textdomain' );
        $text = sprintf( $text, number_format_i18n( $published ) );



            $items[] = sprintf( '<span class="%1$s-count">%2$s</span>', $type, $text ) . "\n";

    }
}

return $items;
 }
```

Comment: I think I found a way around your above WordPress Core hack. I can't upvote your answer, while you have the core hack part in your answer ;-)

Comment: Even if I wrote "-I don't prefer that-" ? :-)

Comment: Instead explain the source code part and remove phrases like *"If you insist doing that, you can hack the Wordpress core manually"* ... well that's my suggestion because I'm afraid some people will not take your warning seriously enough ;-)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I edited my answer :)